# Get data from UNIX socket with Swift on MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, sockets, unix

I want to use a UNIX socket on Macos using Swift to receive some bytes, nothing serious. But I can't get to
to read any data from the socket.

Why UNIX socket? I wanted to have a "simple IPC". I could use TCP/IP, but now I want to make this work.

I did create a socket using SocketPort

```swift
    SocketPort(protocolFamily: AF_UNIX, socketType: SOCK_STREAM, protocol: 0, address: data)
```

I did created an input stream with:

```swift
    (...)
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, port.socket, &readStream, nil)
    (...)
    self.inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
    self.inputStream?.delegate = self
    self.inputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .default)
    self.inputStream?.open()
```

And after running the app, everything seems fine, even the StreamDelegate protocol function 'stream' is called 
back with eventCode for 'openCompleted' after openning the input stream.

Then I send some data with 'socat' but can't get those bytes in the swift app.

I'm using XCode, I added the network entitlements as I read somewhere. But I can't debug the socket. I expected
the 'stream' function to get called once I send some data to the socket.

I read other projects like BlueSocket (I'll give a try later but is not simple to add it to my existing XCode proyect), 
they seem to go low-level ( calling Darwin.socket, Darwin.connect...).

I can provide more code. I don't know where to look at. Any clue? advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this years ago by writing my own implementation of URLProtocol. I was using it for Docker, so I added a URL scheme of "docker". The code has a lot of dependencies, but here is a [a working commit](https://github.com/mlilback/rc2SwiftClient/tree/a5118e872e6e2982c98f9ce5aea98ef3dc54bf27/Docker) where you should be able to get the basic idea.